# Solution of a Quadratic Optimization Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $\mathbf{A_1}$ and $\mathbf{A_2}$ be two given $N\times N$ hermitian matrices. Then how do I solve the problem, 
\begin{align}
\max_{\mathbf{u}~\in~\mathbb{C}^N}~~&\mathbf{u}^H\mathbf{A_1}\mathbf{u} \\
s.t. &\mathbf{u}^H\mathbf{A_2}\mathbf{u}\geq 0 \\
&\mathbf{u}^H\mathbf{u}=1
\end{align}
I already know how to solve it numerically. Note that, without the first constraint, this is the plain rayleigh-ratio.